# In JavaScript, how do I access a function on an object using a string argument?

Tags: javascript

So, for example, I have one function `someObject.doSomething()` & another function `someFunction(whatObject, whatFunction)`. I want to be able to use someFunction like this: `someFunction('someObject', 'doSomething')` and have it call `someObject.doSomething()`.

Basically what I want to do is pass strings to a function that can then use those strings to call other functions.

Comment: you can do more clear question with codes. What have you tried?

Comment: Try writing out what you want as pseudo-code. Then others can let you know if they have a good solution.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I've edited the question above to be less convoluted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could execute a string as code with eval.

```
function execute(objectName, objectFunction){
    eval(objectName + "." + objectFunction+"();");
}

execute("anotherObject", "doSomethingElse");
```

But caution with this command, this might throw a exception if either the object or the function does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two objects, object A & B.

```
A.doSomething = function(){...}
B.doSomethingElse = function(){...}
```

Now for A to doSomethingElse, you can use *call* as so:

```
B.doSomethingElse.call(A);
```

This changes the *this* of doSomethingElse to the scope of A, which makes so the function *doSomethingElse* is applied on A.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
function doIt(obj, fn){ 
  (new Function(obj+"."+fn+"()"))();
};

var A = {b:function(){
  alert("test");
}}

doIt("A", "b");
```